# advantages and disadvantages of using asp.net custom handlers?

Tags: asp.net, security, httphandler

what are the advantages and disadvantages of using asp.net custom handlers such as http handlers and etc? what kind of security issues will I face?

Comment: event handler, http handler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no disadvantages as such. The IHttpHandler is a core concept of asp.net. Any Page instance is also an IHttpHandler. You will face no security issues that you are not already facing.

Hope this answers your question.

/Klaus